# Adding backgroung image behind Appendices title page

Tags: backgrounds, appendix

I'm trying to add a background image behind the appendix title page.

I managed to do it for my book's parts, using the following code:

`{\tikz[remember picture,overlay]\node[inner sep=0pt] at ($(current page.north) +
    (0pt,-400pt)$) {\includegraphics{example-image-a}};}`

But I can't figure out how to make it work for that one Appendices page.

```
% PREAMBLE %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\documentclass[oneside,centered,twocolumn]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\special{papersize=215.9mm,279.4mm}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella} % Palatino clone

\newfontfamily\headingfont[]{TeX Gyre Heros}

%%%%%% APPENDIX FONT CHANGE %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\let\appendixpagenameorig\appendixpagename
\renewcommand{\appendixpagename}{\fontsize{45}{45}\headingfont\appendixpagenameorig}

\begin{document}

\begin{appendices}
    %   \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}}
    %\input{Appendix}

    \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}}
    \makeatletter
    \addtocontents{toc}{%
        \begingroup
        \let\protect\l@chapter\protect\l@section
        \let\protect\l@section\protect\l@subsection
    }
    \makeatother

\chapter{Some title}
\section{Some section}

This city is only a city.

\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are may options to add a background image such as eso-pic and other tikz constructs. And am surprised you have not had many suggestions from everyone !

In principle you are asking for a page "watermark" and many [packages](https://www.ctan.org/search?phrase=watermark) are available.
This one is NOT the best it has a reputation of being difficult to debug *(always ensure you clear auxiliary files after a bad run)* however it is highly configurable as you can see in this example. It may be possible to add code to automatically add the start and end pages. but in a given document you usually know which ones need to be added into preamble e.g. replace the 2-1000 or in this case simply change to 1-1

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
% PREAMBLE %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass[oneside,centered,twocolumn]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\special{papersize=215.9mm,279.4mm}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella} % Palatino clone
\newfontfamily\headingfont[]{TeX Gyre Heros}

% WATERMARK ADDITIONS %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[printwatermark]{xwatermark}
\newwatermark[pages=2-1000,color=black!10,angle=15,scale=0.8,xpos=0,ypos=10]{\includegraphics{example-image}}

\usepackage{mwe} % for example images

% APPENDIX FONT CHANGE %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\let\appendixpagenameorig\appendixpagename
\renewcommand{\appendixpagename}{\fontsize{45}{45}\headingfont\appendixpagenameorig}

\begin{document}

\begin{appendices}
    %   \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}}
    %\input{Appendix}

    \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}}
    \makeatletter
    \addtocontents{toc}{%
        \begingroup
        \let\protect\l@chapter\protect\l@section
        \let\protect\l@section\protect\l@subsection
    }
    \makeatother

\chapter{Some title}
\section{Some section}

This city is only a city.

\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to do this. It works well.